# Can I manage/change the default flash message text?

Tags: users, session, app

I am looking to customise the default flash message text for certain behaviours but cannot seem to find any reference to them in the code or control panel - does this exist anywhere? And could it be made editable in the CP?

I know I could do something like this but it feels hacky:

```
{% if craft.app.session.getFlash('notice') == 'User registered.' %}
  {% do craft.app.session.setFlash('notice', 'User registered - please check your email to activate your account.') %}
{% endif %}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could for example just edit the translation file with the specific [user registered flash message.](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/translations/en/app.php#L1043)

You can read more about the static translation in the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#static-translation-files).

Comment: That would do it - thanks.